# Eclipse content assist failing in migrated workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, rad, content-assist

The situation:

We migrated to new workstations. I copied all of my workspaces over. On the old workstation, I had both RAD 7.5 (based on Eclipse 3.4) and Eclipse 4.3. On the new workstation, I have only RAD 8.5 (based on Eclipse 3.6). So far, the only problem I've had has been when I opened an Eclipse 4.3 workspace in RAD 8.5 and I discovered that Content Assist simply doesn't work. I can type `this.` and wait, and then nothing happens for a few seconds, and then the little red underline appears under the text. I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and the content-assist window appears - and it's *empty*!

What's interesting is that the legacy-RAD 7.5 workspaces *don't* have this problem - it only happens with the workspaces that were created with Eclipse 4.3. I've tried using the "Restore Defaults" button in the Preferences page, I've tried exporting preferences from my legacy-RAD 7.5 workspaces and importing to my legacy-Eclipse 4.3 workspaces, but content assist still doesn't work.

I'm guessing that there's some piece of meta-data that needs to be recreated by RAD 8.5 but I'm not sure which one that is... Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can enable the content assist manually.

Window--->Preferences--->Java---->Editor----Content Assist---->Advanced

Make sure you have "Java Proposals" selected.

[image]

Comment: Yup, that was it! I guess that setting got changed somehow between Eclipse 4.3 and RAD 8.5...